# passport - nodejs - returning user to previous page after facebook auth

Tags: javascript, facebook, passport.js

I'm new to passport and am trying to redirect a user to the page that they were previously on after authenticating with facebook.  I am trying to set a "req.session.returnTo" property on the session, but it keeps getting wiped out in the facebook/auth callback (everywhere in that function it turns up as undefined).  What is wrong with my approach?

Protected route:

```
app.post('/api/recipebox', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {

});
```

ensureAuthenticated:

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next();
    }

      req.session.returnTo = req.path;

      res.redirect('/#!/login');

  }
```

//Facebook/Passport.js callback:

```
 app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function (req, res, next) {

    passport.authenticate('facebook', function (err, user, redirectURL) {
      // console.log(' in the callback ');
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.redirect('/#!/login');
      }

      if (!user) {
        return res.redirect('/#!/signup');
      }
      if (req.user) {
        // console.log("==================== This is the user from routes.js", req.user);
        res.cookie('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      }
      //actually storing the fact that they are logged in:
      req.login(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return res.redirect('/#!/login');
        }

        // console.log('=========== here!', user);
        res.redirect(req.session.returnTo || '/#!');
        req.session.returnTo = null;

      });
    })(req, res, next);
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this on the client:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {

    return {
      request: function (request) {
        // console.log("hello");
        // console.log(window.location.href);
        request.headers.lastUrl = window.location.href;
        return request;
      },
      responseError: function (response) {
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
    };
  });
```

and this on the server:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  //req.session.returnTo is available everywhere in router now.
  //filter if it not auth/login/signup, then save it.  only update return to when it's not one of those.  
  if (req.get('lastUrl') !== undefined) {

    var lastUrl = req.get('lastUrl');

    if (lastUrl.indexOf("login") === -1 && lastUrl.indexOf("signup") === -1 && lastUrl !== "http://localhost:3000/#!/") {

      req.session.returnTo = lastUrl;
    }
    console.log(req.session);
  }
  next();
});
```

Hope it helps others. I did not have luck with the successRedirect and i don't think it would be that simple if you end up being at pages like login/signup/taken away from the page all together.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Local strategy for an email and password login. I referred to the following link to setup my passport JS authentication and login: [Passport Facebook](http://passportjs.org/docs/facebook)

1. Use the Facebook Strategy as seen in the above link.
2. Use the routing as seen below

   ```
   app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',passport.authenticate('facebook',
                                    successRedirect: 'whatever-url-you-want', 
                                    failureRedirect: '/login' }));
   ```